# Exercise 3.1.23 in Salamon's Functional Analysis

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-convergence, weak-topology

I'm reading the book *Functional Analysis* written by Dietmar A. Salamon.The following problem is the exercise 3.1.23 in the book.

Let **X** be a Banach space and suppose the dual space of **X** is separable.Let **S** be a bounded subset of **X** and let **x** be an element in the weak closure of **S**.

I want to prove that there is a sequence in **S** that converges weakly to **x**.
I don't know how to use the condition that **X** is a Banach space.

Any hint would be helpful,thanks a lot!

Comment: The weak topology on the unit ball (thus on any ball) is metrizable, due to separability of $X^*.$

Comment: @Ryszard Szwarc Is the completeness of X necessary?

Comment: I think it is not essential. The dual space of $X$ and of the completion of $X$ are identical.